# How can i set an audio file for video clip with moviepy without re encoding

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

So far i tried:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
videoclip = VideoFileClip("filename.mp4")
audioclip = AudioFileClip("audioname.mp3")

new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
videoclip.write_videofile("new_filename.mp4")
```

But it takes very long time.
I'd like to do it without re encoding. i also prefer opening video or audio clip from bytes in moviepy

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `ffmpeg_merge_video_audio` from [FFMPEG tools](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/ffmpeg.html).

`ffmpeg_merge_video_audio` - merges video file video and audio file audio into one movie file output.
By default the merging is performed without re-encoding.

---

Code sample:

```
from moviepy.video.io import ffmpeg_tools
ffmpeg_tools.ffmpeg_merge_video_audio("filename.mp4", "audioname.mp3", 'new_filename.mp4')  # Merge audio and video without re-encoding
```

---

Note:
As far as I know, it's not possible to do it "from bytes" using MoviePy.

Comment: this is the right answer reading from bytes needed other libraries